# Subsetting a dataframe by a vector: Removing quantiles

Tags: r, vector, dataframe, subset, quantile

This is a more complicated iteration of previous questions about subsetting a dataframe by a vector.  So in this case I have a very large dataframe with numerous columns of crop data in it.  Within that dataframe is a column entitled "STshort" which has lots of tail errors in it.  I want to take remove the upper 10% and lower 10% of values from this column and have attempted it in the following manner.

First I make an object for the column "STshort" as shown below.

```
sh<-Maindata[,"STShort"]
```

Then I try to subset the data frame by the quintiles of this column in the following manner.  This logic has typically worked for subsetting a vector.

```
Maindata<-Maindata[sh>=(quantile(sh,.10,na.rm=TRUE))&sh<=(quantile(sh,.9,na,rm=TRUE)),]
```

I get the following error message.

> Error in quantile.default(sh, 0.1, na.rm = TRUE) : 
>     factors are not allowed

Some of my data in this column

```
dput(sh[1:10])

structure(c(73L, 54L, 145L, 127L, 37L, 115L, 102L, 119L, 239L, 
198L), .Label = c("-10536.5041", "-1081.8875", "-11360.69846", 
"-1179.834949", "-1241.222986", "-1259.302658", "-1277.333333", 
"-1286.085441", "-1289.74", "-1294", "-1333.25", "-1334.138686", 
"-1335.521379", "-1369.85455", "-13715.36843", "-1376.361502", 
"-1380.27099", "-14.39869997", "-143.0545455", "-1516.133764", 
"-156.2526551", "-1579.5", "-15917.49503", "-1683.4375", "-1699.0625",
```

Any ideas on how one could conceivably go about this?

Comment: Use `class(sh)` if it is factor, then you have to change it to numeric.

Comment: It would help if you provided some of your data by posting the output of `dput(sh[1:10])`.

Comment: `as.numeric(as.character(sh))`

Comment: The problem is the way that R reads the "STShort" column. You must change its class to numeric from the beginning.

Comment: If you don't provide the full `dput`, it's hardly any use.